# Ractive template does not work with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, ractivejs

[Jsfiddle - JQuery accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/JWfdx/24/)

Attempted with ractive template for the first time - whole html copied and pasted into the template. Also JQuery was in separate file.

```
<a id="test" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-signup">Sign up new account</a>
    <div id="modal-signup" data-js-test>
```

this code was on full index page, but modal was in different template file.

```
$("#test").click(function(){

    var sign =  new Ractive({
      el: document.querySelector('[data-js-test]'),
      template: '#template',
      data : {
        error: false
      }

    });
```

But the accordion is not working - it does not slide up or down as shown in jsfiddle. I am not sure if it is because of ractive : `<script id="template" type='text/ractive'>` with html. 
Is there a way around it? Attempted with CSS3 but there is no way to make tab collapse or expand like this jsfiddle example.

Help or guide will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just wanting to use Ractive to make this data-driven? Or are you also looking for doing the accordion-slide functionality with Ractive?

Comment: @martypdx - both - accordion form will be data-driven (more like matching fields before register is approved) and yes i have been looking on google for accordion slide functionality with ractive, but I am kinda lost in how ractive works.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping with the basic design you have, you can do this (see http://jsfiddle.net/kDUhU/1 for full example). Organize your html like:

```
<a id="test" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-signup">Sign up new account</a>
    <div id="modal-signup" data-js-test>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    //ractive template goes here, see fiddle for full example
</script>
```

then in your javascript:

```
$("#test").click(function(){

    var sign =  new Ractive({
      el: document.querySelector('[data-js-test]'),
      template: '#template',
      data : {
          error: false,
          steps: [
              { 
                  name: 'Step 1 - Information',
                  color: 'yellow',
                  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc...'
              },
              ...
          ]
      }
    })

    // now apply your accordion logic
    $('.accordion div.content').slideToggle(0) 
    ...

});
```

For a more "ractive" based example, you can use the slide plugin (see http://jsfiddle.net/kDUhU/2/). I've stripped much of the format attributing for clarity, basically your template becomes:

```
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <a href="#" on-click='show'>Sign up new account</a>
    {{# selected > -1 }}
    <div>
        <h3>Sign up a new account</h3>
        <div class="accordion">
            {{#steps:i}}
            <div id="step-{{i+1}}">
                <a href="#" on-click='select'>{{name}}</a>
                {{#selected===i}}
                <div intro-outro='slide' style="background: {{color}};">
                    {{content}}
                </div>
                {{/}}
            </div>
            {{/}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/}}
</script>
```

And your js is

```
var sign =  new Ractive({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data : {
        steps: [
              { 
                  name: 'Step 1 - Information',
                  color: 'yellow',
                  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc'
              },
              ...
          ]
      }
})

sign.on('show', function(){
    this.set('selected', 0)
    sign.off('show')
})
sign.on('select', function(e){
    this.set('selected', e.index.i)  
})
```

Lastly, a bit jenky with some limits, but just for good fun, here's a pure CSS accordian: http://jsfiddle.net/kDUhU/4/

key part of template:

```
<label for='step{{i}}'>{{name}}</label>
<input name='steps' type='radio' id='step{{i}}' checked='{{i===0}}'>
<div intro-outro='slide' style="background: {{color}};">
    {{content}}
</div>
```

css:

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + div {
    max-height: 0;
}
input[type=radio] + div {
    max-height: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;

}
```